# Is it possible to use Browserify API with string contents of some JS files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am working on a hobby project in **node.js**, and I am trying to use Browserify API on the way. I have an object, that contains JS file names as keys, JS file contents as names. Something like:

```
var obj = {
 "a.js": { content: "require('test/b.js'); var hello = 1;" },
 "test/b.js": { content: "var b = 1;" },
}
```

(both `content` fields have actual javascript file contents.)

I want to browserify these "virtual" files. **I don't want to write them to disk and read from disk**, I want to do an **in memory operation**. Something like:

`var out = browserify(obj)`

```
/// out variable contains

var b = 1;
var hello = 1;

/// no disk action at all
```

Is it possible to use browserify API if I have string contents of some JS files, without actually reading or writing them to file system?

Comment: @dandavis That `a.js` and `test/b.js` are virtual, doesn't exists anywhere but in that object. But key names follow a virtual directory structure.

Comment: Well, that file container object will be programmatically generated from some sources at some point, so it may be large and complex. Therefore that would be great if I am able to just pass it to browserify.

Comment: Hey Umut, did you find a solution by any chance? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else is looking for this.
I did find out that you can have [readable streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) being sent to browserify as an argument so it would work like this:

```
var s = new require('stream').Readable(),
    path = require('path').parse(process.cwd() + '/' + filePath);

s.push(fileContents);
s.push(null);

browserify(s, { basedir: path.dir }).bundle(callback);
```

Pay attention that you also need to specify the optional `basedir` parameter in case you script is located else where other than the current working directory.

As far as I could understand it's possible to use the `entries` of the option parameter in order to add more files to the bundle, perhaps those can also be readable streams? [more here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifyfiles--opts)

I have also [submitted a request](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1523) so this can be better documented in the future, perhaps pointing users to the right direction.